# I have a segmentation fault (core dumped) when using strcpy, malloc, and struct

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Okay, when I run this code, I have a segmentation fault:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 64

struct example {
    char *name;
};

int main()
{
    struct example *s = malloc (MAX); 
    strcpy(s->name ,"Hello World!!");
    return !printf("%s\n", s->name);
}
```

the terminal output:

```
alshamlan@alshamlan-VGN-CR520E:/tmp/interview$ make q1
cc -Wall -g    q1.c   -o q1
alshamlan@alshamlan-VGN-CR520E:/tmp/interview$ ./q1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
alshamlan@alshamlan-VGN-CR520E:/tmp/interview$ gedit q1.c
```

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: You want your string to be size MAX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have allocated memory for your struct, but not for its character pointer.

You can't perform a strcpy onto memory that isn't allocated. You could say

```
s->name = "Hello World";
```

instead.

Alternatively, allocate memory for your char, and then perform the copying.
**NOTE**: I in NO way endorse that the following code is good, just that it will work.

```
int main()
{
  struct example *s = malloc(MAX);
  s->name = malloc(MAX);
  strcpy(s->name ,"Hello World!!");
  return !printf("%s\n", s->name);
}
```

---

Edit: Here is perhaps a cleaner implementation, but I still hate C-style strings

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define KNOWN_GOOD_BUFFER_SIZE 64

typedef struct example {
  char *name;
} MyExample;

int main()
{
  MyExample *s = (MyExample*) malloc( sizeof(MyExample) );
  s->name = (char*) malloc(KNOWN_GOOD_BUFFER_SIZE);
  strcpy(s->name ,"Hello World!!");
  printf("%s\n", s->name);
  free(s->name);
  free(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating memory for the struct, but the char *name is still pointing to uninitialized memory. You need to allocate memory for the char * as well. If you want it to be a string of max size 64, which you can change after creation, try this:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 64

struct example {
    char *name;
};

int main()
{
    struct example *s = malloc(sizeof(struct example)); 
    s->name = malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(s->name ,"Hello World!!");
    return !printf("%s\n", s->name);
}
```

Note I'm allocating the MAX only to the char *. The example struct only needs to be sizeof(struct example)), so there's no point making it MAX. This is a better approach, as your malloc will keep giving you the exact right size, even if you change the members of your example struct.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are allocating memory for `s` but not for `s->name` and so you are performing indirection on an uninitialized pointer which is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Going on the assumption that you really want to allocate space for one `struct example` and you want your string to be size `MAX` then you want the following allocations:

```
struct example *s = malloc (sizeof(struct example)); 
s->name = malloc(MAX*sizeof(char)) ;
```

Note the use of [operator sizeof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) to determine the correct size of the *data type* you are allocating memory for.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct example *s = malloc (MAX);
```

That line points s to a memory capable of holding 64 example structures. Each example structure only has enough memory to hold a pointer (called name).

```
strcpy(s->name ,"Hello World!!");
```

Thats not valid, as s->name isn't pointing anywhere, it needs to point to allocated memory.

You probably want:

```
struct example *s = malloc(sizeof(struct example)); //Allocate one example structure
s->name = malloc(MAX); //allocate 64 bytes for name 
strcpy(s->name,"Hello world!"); //This is ok now.
```

This is the same as:

```
struct example s;  //Declare example structure
s.name = malloc(MAX);  //allocate 64 bytes to name
strcpy(s.name,"Hello world!");
```